# CSS3 Transitions In Drop Down Menu - Invisible 3rd Level Menu Items Appearing On Hover Before Mousing Over 2nd Level

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, opacity

I am creating a basic HTML/CSS3 drop down menu. I'm also trying to use a fading transition effect on the drop downs. An example of the issue I am having is in the screencast video below:

http://tinypic.com/r/95r2tt/5

The drop down menu items are set to an opacity of 0 that fades into an opacity of 1. The problem is, when I mouse over an area where they third level menu items are, they appear before mousing over the top level and 2nd level menus first. However, if I try to use display:none and display:block on them to make them appear/disappear then the transition effects don't work. Any ideas? I tried a recommendation of setting the height to 0 then Auto but that didn't seem to work.

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mymenu {
    background-color: #000;
}
.mymenu ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.mymenu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.mymenu ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.mymenu ul li a:link, .mymenu ul li a:visited {
    background-color: #900;
}
.mymenu ul li a:hover, .mymenu ul li a:active {
    background-color: #000;
}
.mymenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
       -moz-transition: all .5s;
        -ms-transition: all .5s;
         -o-transition: all .5s;
            transition: all .5s;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
}

.mymenu ul li ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li a:link, .mymenu ul li ul li a:visited {
    background-color: #C00;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li a:hover, .mymenu ul li ul li a:active {
    background-color: #000;
}
.mymenu ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 95%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li ul li a:link, .mymenu ul li ul li ul li a:visited {
    background-color: #F90;
}
.mymenu ul li ul li ul li a:hover, .mymenu ul li ul li ul li a:active {
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code to it? And possibly generate a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: I found a solution to this, it's to use the visibility:hidden/visibility:visible properties in conjunction with the opacity/transition effects as opposed to using display:none/display:block.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this, it's to use visibility:hidden/visibility:visible along with the change in opacity, as opposed to using the display:none/display:block properties.